# Can Dropbox under OS X be accessed from a command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, dropbox

I want to access Dropbox in my Mac from a remote location with ssh. Is there any way to access Dropbox from the OS X command line?

Comment: What's preventing you from just going to the Dropbox folder on your Mac?

Comment: Are you on OS X and want to access a Dropbox folder on a remote machine?  Are you on OS X and want to access a Dropbox folder locally via command line?  Do you want to access a Dropbox folder on OS X *from* a remote machine?  Your question isn't clear

Comment: If you have Dropbox installed, it behaves like a normal folder so just a `cd ~/Dropbox` (if using the default) would work.

Comment: @BrianKintz I want to acess my Dropbox remotely. So i want to know is there a way to have commandline access to Dropbox

Comment: Have you tried just entering `dropbox` in command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accessing cd /Users/$home-user/Dropbox  solved my question

Answer (score 1):

If you have both a company and personal dropbox it can be more complicated because both the space and the parens need to be escaped or quoted.  In this case your cd looks more like:

```
cd /Users/$home-user/Dropbox\ \(Company Name\)/
```

or

```
cd "/Users/$home-user/Dropbox (Company Name)/"
```

Comment: It's simpler to put the whole thing in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Previously the location of the Dropbox folder was:

```
/Users/$home-user/Dropbox
```

For the most recent version it has changed to:

```
/Users/$home-user/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox
```